# What is the difference in this question between $\log$ and $\lg$?

Tags: logarithms

Am I right in assuming that $\lg$ just refers to $\log$ base ($10$)? Whereas $\log$ is just any unspecified log?

I'm solving $\lg{15}-\lg{5}$

Am I good to just use the standard rules of logarithms, where subtraction is concerned?

Comment: $\lg = \log_2$ is common.

Comment: $\lg$ is the same as $\log_2$.

Comment: Ah okay, so I'm solving lg2(15) - lg2(5)?

Comment: @NewZealand'sfinest: Yes, except that when you use $\lg$, you don’t add the subscript $2$: it’s understood. You have $\lg 15-\lg 5=\log_215-\log_25$.

Comment: Great, thanks for your help!

I'm happy for this question to be closed if it isn't going to contribute to anybody else.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Particular_bases) suggests lg is $\log_{10}$ while ln is $\log_e$ and lb is $\log_2$, as suggested by ISO 31-11, though some use lg for $\log_2$

Comment: Brian, what would 2ln8 represent?

Comment: @NewZealand'sfinest It would be $2\log_e8$ where $e$ is Euler's constant.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! You're a star.

Comment: If I were asked to simplify 2ln8 - ln5 + 2ln10, am I able to solve this as before using the log rules and without being concerned by Euler's constant at all? Purely because it states to simplify, and not to solve.

Answer (score 3):

$\lg3$ is the answer :)

Because $\lg{\dfrac{15}{5}}=\lg{3}$

Comment: If the answer is $lg3$ then you don't really care if it means $\log_2$ or $\log_{10}$ :)

Answer (score 0):

In general, the use of $lg$ is ambiguous. Therefore this problem is not properly stated, it should have been explicitly mentioned what $lg$ means. Of course, if that's just an exercise after some lesson, and that lesson defines what exactly $lg$ is, then the problem is stated fine.